# How to make a binary executable able to write anywhere on linux?

Tags: devops

I am writing a tool for all users on a linux server, which can download files from somewhere and save them to current directory. I build this tool as sudo user `vector` to get a binary executable and ask others to use `alias tool="path/to/binary"` to access that executable. However this executable cannot write files other than in folders under home directory of `vector`. How can I do to make it accessable to all users and have permissions to write to their directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the tool, vector can own it.
The tool should reside somewhere on the user's PATH.
/usr/bin or /usr/local/bin are usually included the PATH.
You can check the path with `echo $PATH` to see what it is set to.

Check the permissions to make sure it is executable by everyone.
`chmod 755 /path/to/binary`

When the user executes the tool, it should execute as the user.

Make sure the output of the tool is not hard-code to a location the user does not have access to write.

If you can have it write to STDOUT, then the user can redirect the output to a place of their choosing

`cmd> /path/to/binary > ~/output.txt`

Comment: Thanks! Really helped me a lot. BTW, what's the difference between using `alias` and using `$PATH`?

Comment: an alias is a shortcut that you create for a command.
For example, I have an alias defined as
lad=`ls -al | grep ^d`
This alias shows me all the directories in my current directory.
When I have this alias defined, instead of typing those commands every time, I can now just time lad at the command line.

$PATH is just a collection of directories, but it's a special environment variable in linux.  If there is an executable in one of those directories, you don't have to type the full path to it.  Instead of /bin/ls, you can just type ls.